# Is TabLayout supposed to replace PagerTabStrip? Is there any "pro" to PagerTabStrip?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-tabs, android-support-design

OK, so I see PagerTabStrip has a bug - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183127

Therefore, is TabLayout a better choice especially for now?
 Is there any downside to TabLayout? Some quirkiness where you might have to set all 3 items?

I see [TabLayout versus pagerTabStrip for convenience and functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301184/tablayout-versus-pagertabstrip-for-convenience-and-functionality) but that didn't really get answers...

Comment: "is TabLayout a better choice especially for now?" -- that, or any one of the [many third-party libraries offering tab implementations](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111). "Is there any downside to TabLayout?" -- it requires that you use `AppCompatActivity`, which you may or may not be interested in.

Comment: Thanks, that's better than "because it's newer" although it'd be nice if there was something official...