# Difference between PagerTabStrip and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, pagertabstrip

I am working on an app where I want to add tabs so that can be added using `PagerTabStrip` and `TabLayout` with ViewPager.

It looks same to me with no difference but I guess there is some difference between them so they are two classes for this. So what is the main difference between them?

Comment: TabLayout  cotainer a PagerTabStrip in it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just comparing the visuals...

[`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) is a material concept that replaced the deprecated [ActionBar tabs](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments) in Android 5.0.
It extends `HorizontalScrollView`, so you can keep adding tabs horizontally which can include text, icons, or custom views and scroll through them linearly without paging.

`TabLayout` provides the [`setupWithViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) method to **attach to** a `ViewPager` instead of being **part of** the `ViewPager` like the `PagerTabStrip`.

[image: TabLayout]

A `PagerTabStrip` is more of an indictor for the current page of a ViewPager, and "it is intended to be used as a child view of a ViewPager widget". The scrolling for it does not act like the `TabLayout` since each tab is part of the page instead of individually horizontally scrollable.

[image: PagerTabStrip]

In summary, the differences are (apart from visuals).

1. A `TabLayout` is **part of the Activity/Fragment**, outside of the `ViewPager`, and you instead attach it to one. It scrolls separately from the pages.
2. A `PagerTabStrip` is **a child element of the `ViewPager`**. The tabs scroll with the page.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) I can say that the TabLayout is the material design concept and as all knows it's new concept than the PagerTabStrip.

You can check the base hierarchy for both

1) TabLayout Hirarchy

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.widget.FrameLayout
               ↳    android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
                   ↳    android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

2) PagerTabStrip Hirarchy

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
               ↳    android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
```

For more detail check [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) and [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)