# Is it possible to create swipeable toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I want to create a second toolbar with all the menu items directing to different activities instead of creating a viewpager with different fragments. I tried to look for example online but all the examples I found are related to viewpager with fragments or collapsing toolbar. Is it possible to have a "swipeable" toolbar so that all menu items can be displayed instead of putting some of the items on overflow button? The layout I have right now is as follows. Thank you so much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ken.android_gam24.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_bar_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/supportToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="159dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="159dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668443/difference-between-pagertabstrip-and-tablayout/35755711#35755711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest a `HorizontalScrollview` inside your `Toolbar` layout:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!-- Buttons -->
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Or use a `TabLayout`

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking of using [navigationview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html). The example of its implementation is in this [link](http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/).

Or you can use the one suggested by mrsegev: use [HorizontalScrollview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) in your [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) as it is also a view group.

[image]